# DNS updating issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I'm new to serverfault so please excuse me if I sound a tad nub.  I work in an environment that is kinda peace mealed together, and I honestly don't know how it works.  I'm new to the IT field and am still in school.

When I replace a PC I rename the old one to mo-o-pcname and give the new one the proper name of mo-pcname (mo is a location thing we use so it really doesn't apply to the problem.)

The new PC will function on the network; it will have the ability to access network resources (printers, file shares, etc) and it will have the ability to get out to the internet.

However I can no longer ping the machine.  It would appear as if the DNS (A) record is not getting updated or something.  Like I said I'm kinda new to the field and just trying to work through this problem.

Comment: So how should I clean up the current setup so that all the PC's have the right PC to IP address translation?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a windows environment, then what you would do is log in to the DNS server, normally the Domain Controller and Access de DNS management snap in, then you should modify the A recort of the Forward Lookup Zone, here is a how to: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/dns/how-do-i-add-a-record-to-the-dns-.aspx

Comment: Also, you should read about dynamic updates if you have an Active Directory Domain setup. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816592

Comment: Thanks, we do have dynamic updates set up on the DHCP server.It set to enable DNS dynamic updates and always dynamically update DNS A and PTR records, and to discard A and PTR records when the lease is deleted. The thing is that I would think I should not have to go into the DNS server everytime I swap out a computer.  I take it this is happening because the computer is getting a new IP address? Like it used to see MO-PCNAME as 172.16.100.20 and when I renamed it then did it automatically update the DNS to say MO-O-PCNAME is now 172.16.100.20 and now the NEW MO-PCNAME is say 172.16.100.21?

Comment: I guess I just don't have a firm understanding on how DNS works, it was covered in some of my classes, but its different when you are dealing with a real life application of it.

Comment: On the DHCP server I see that there were two entries for MO-PCNAME I deleted one but that really didn't help. If I delete all records for it in the address lease area would it then go to the DHCP and get a new address and update the A record in DNS?

Comment: did you first removed the old machine from the Domain and Then Joined this new one?. i would suggest to remove the old machine first, delete any DNS records that may remain, and then join the New computer to the domain. let us know how it went

Answer (score 0):

I second Hugo's advice. The cleanest method is to remove the machine from the domain, then join the new machine with the new name. That way the changes to the DNS are communicated from the domain controller(s) and with no needed intervention to the DNS.